# How can I modify css (e.g. position) of Wicket's activity indicator?

Tags: css, wicket

I am using IAjaxIndicatorAware for a panel containing several elements able to call AJAX. The indicator shows currently under the panel and I need to change its position - how should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you use IAjaxIndicatorAware then you have a Wicket Component that implements IAjaxIndicatorAware. In that case Wicket just makes the HTML element with id == IAjaxIndicatorAware#getAjaxIndicatorMarkupId visible by using `jQuery.show($('#indicatorId'))`. This HTML element is placed by you somewhere in your page so you have full control on it. For example you can add CSS rule like:

```
#indicatorId {
   // padding: ...
   // margin: ...
}
```

But if you use `org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.AjaxIndicatorAppender` then you should use the CSS class returned by `org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.AjaxIndicatorAppender#getSpanClass()` as a CSS selector.